# Is it important that the framer add extra plate to the floor instead of putting the load bearing stud directly on the plywood?

Tags: drywall, framing, studs, load-bearing

I brought a licensed contractor to reframe the kitchen door, expand the laundry closet into a nook, and remove some of the studs to eliminate a linen closet.

First, they did a very bad job, cutting studs too short and removing load-bearing studs without adding a header. So they came back a second time and added back some of the studs that they didn't even need to remove in the first place.

But this time, since they cut the floor plates the first time, they didn't add any more floor plates and put the studs directly on the plywood. This is bugging me.

Is this a dealbreaker? I feel when they put straight pressure on the floor without distributing the pressure. Why didn't they add another piece of plate to the floor before adding back load-bearing studs and headers?

I am posting some photos with the hope to get some relief or advice about this issue on what to do next?

[image: stud framing]

[image: corner framing]

Comment: How do you know those are load bearing studs? Also, you have no picture of the header, so its hard for us to see exactly what is going on.

Comment: Pix are too small to really see what's going on there.